# Assigning integer values from variadic template list to static const std::array member

Tags: c++, templates, static-members, variadic, stdarray

Consider the following code snippet:

```
template<unsigned... IDs>
class MyClass{
public:
    static const std::array<unsigned, sizeof...(IDs)> ids { IDs... };
    PinIDs() = default;
};
```

Then use the class as:

```
MyClass<1,5,7,9> myClass;
```

The Objective would be to have `ids` with a size of 4, and contain the values: (1,5,7,9) respectively.

Is this type object possible or would I have to remove the static qualifier? If not how would one write this with the static qualifier. The object needs to be default constructible.

---

**EDIT:**

<strike>I tried Apple Apple's first solution and with MS Visual Studio 2017 CE on Win7
I got this compiler error:</strike>

> ```
>  1>------ Build started: Project: PracticeMath, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
> 1>stdafx.cpp
> 1>PracticeMath.cpp
> 1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\practicemath\practicemath\practicemath.cpp(33): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
> 1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\practicemath\practicemath\practicemath.cpp(33): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
> 1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\practicemath\practicemath\practicemath.cpp(33): error C2059: syntax error: '<'
> 1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\practicemath\practicemath\practicemath.cpp(33): error C2039: 'ids': is not a member of '`global namespace''
> 1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\practicemath\practicemath\practicemath.cpp(33): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
> 1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\practicemath\practicemath\practicemath.cpp(33): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
> 1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\practicemath\practicemath\practicemath.cpp(38): error C2065: 'myId': undeclared identifier
> 1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\practicemath\practicemath\practicemath.cpp(39): error C2065: 'myId': undeclared identifier
> 1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\practicemath\practicemath\practicemath.cpp(40): error C2065: 'myId': undeclared identifier
> 1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\practicemath\practicemath\practicemath.cpp(44): error C2065: 'c': undeclared identifier
> 1>Done building project "PracticeMath.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
> ```

With full original source like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<unsigned... IDs>
class PinIDs{
public:
    static const std::array<unsigned, sizeof...(IDs)> ids;

    PinIDs() = default;

    const unsigned& operator[]( unsigned idx ) const {
        return ids[idx];
    }
};

template<unsigned... IDs>
const std::array<unsigned, sizeof...(IDs)> PinIDs<IDs...>::ids { IDs... };

int main() {
    PinIDs<4, 17, 19> myId;

    std::cout << myId[0] << " ";
    std::cout << myId[1] << " ";
    std::cout << myId[2] << " ";

    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit." << std::endl;
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to StoryTeller bringing up the fact that when I tried to apply Apple Apple's `1st method` I accidently mixed up `MyClass` as opposed to the actual name of the class in my solution - project. Once I corrected that it does compile, build and run as expected.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes; but was having trouble... don't know if the `template` syntax business, or just because of using `static`...

Comment: If you "have trouble", paste the error you get

Comment: @PasserBy I understand the errors; it's just the `template syntax` that gets me at times...

Comment: btw, are you bound to a specific C++ version?

Comment: @StoryTeller I have VS2013, 15 & 17 on Windows 7; for this I'm working in 2017...  I should have majority support for C++11 & 14, with very little support for c++17.

Comment: You mix up `MyClass` and `PinIDs` all over the place.

Comment: @StoryTeller; no I originally had PinIDs in my IDe; I just retyped it generically using MyClass when originally asking the question. Before I posted I just swapped MyClass for PinIDs.

Comment: @FrancisCugler - You mix it up in your original code sample (the c'tor), and in applying apple apple's' answer (.`MyClass<IDs...>::ids`). You should pay closer attention.

Comment: @StoryTeller Ah thank you for the over look; starting to get tired... trying to get this to work like I want before the end of the night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this

---

```
#include <array>

template<unsigned... IDs>
class MyClass{
public:
   static const std::array<unsigned, sizeof...(IDs)> ids;
   MyClass() = default;
};

template<unsigned... IDs>
const std::array<unsigned, sizeof...(IDs)> MyClass<IDs...>::ids {IDs...};

int main(){
   MyClass<1,5,7,9> myClass;
   return myClass.ids[0];
}
```

---

or use constexpr/inline (both need c++17)

---

```
#include <array>
template<unsigned... IDs>
class MyClass{
public:
    //static constexpr std::array<unsigned, sizeof...(IDs)> ids{IDs...};//or this
    static inline const std::array<unsigned, sizeof...(IDs)> ids{IDs...};
    MyClass() = default;
};

int main(){
MyClass<1,5,7,9> myClass;
    return myClass.ids[0];
}
```

Comment: Hmm pretty close; I was able to get my class to work as expected without the `static` qualifier. Just that when I tried to make the member variable of static type; is where I was getting into a bit of trouble.

Comment: @FrancisCugler - This is how you'd do it with a static member. It need to be defined outside the class.

Comment: Also I would like to add a `operator[]` to the class that will index directly into the `array` so I don't have to use `object.ids[]` or `MyClass::ids[]`

Comment: I know that much; same as having const static member variables; I've used them before. Just not with templates... and that is where I was struggling because of the syntax.

Comment: I tried your first approach and got the following Compiler Error: see edit below my question:

Comment: I can use the `constexpr` version but not the `inline` version.

Comment: @FrancisCugler maybe your compiler not support it yet, [here is a working example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/y4j55TWOw5iNCJAW)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to @apple apple's answer for the basics. I'll just add the C++17 way to do it. Which is quite close to your original attempt. Just add an `inline` specifier to the variable:

```
template<unsigned... IDs>
class MyClass{
public:
    static inline const std::array<unsigned, sizeof...(IDs)> ids{ { IDs... } };
    MyClass() = default;
};
```

Now the declaration can double as a definition. Oh, and mind the braces. `std::array` needs to be initialized as an aggregate. So one pair of `{}` for the `std::array`, and one for the internal raw array it holds.

Comment: hmm I knew you could use `inline` on `member functions`; just didn't know you could use it on `member variables`...

Comment: @FrancisCugler - Only from C++17 onward.

Comment: Oh okay, I see; a new language feature that MS Visual Studio is probably lacking on...

Comment: @FrancisCugler - Depends on your MSVC version, as ever :)

Comment: yeah my version states `C2433: ... :  'inline' not permitted on data declarations`...

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just try it with [online compiler, supporting c++17](https://wandbox.org/)?

```
template<unsigned... IDs>
class MyClass{
public:
    static constexpr std::array<unsigned, sizeof...(IDs)> ids { IDs... };
    MyClass() = default;
};
```

works fine. You don't need `static const inline` for variables, which are computed at compile time, just use `static constexpr`

Comment: are `constexpr` default constructible?

Comment: @FrancisCugler, `constexpr` values are computed at compile-time. `static` fields in no way interfere with type traits of a class (including default constructibility).

Comment: *"constexpr values are computed"* - No, they *may* be computed at compile time. And even then the array is still likely gonna occupy storage. Because `operator[]` is an ODR-use.

Comment: @StoryTeller, *occupies storage* doesn't imply *not computed at compile time*. Values of this array (along with its size) are defined at compile-time and may be statically checked.

Comment: @AndreiR. - I never said the storage precludes it. The storage argument is to clarify that it isn't something that exists "just at compile time". And yes, the values *may* be used when compiling. Emphasis on *may*. `constexpr` is great, but sometimes it fails us. Only way to know is to examine the generated object files.